# Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to write a function as follow:

```
Function getEntityCode(fileName As String) As Range
Dim entitySheet As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim valid As Boolean
Dim finalRow As Integer
Dim finalCol As Integer

Set entitySheet = Workbooks("OHUploads.xlsm").Worksheets("EntityCodes")
finalRow = entitySheet.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
With entitySheet
   Set c = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(1, finalCol))
End With
valid = False
ErrHandler:
Debug.Print Error(Err)
If valid = False Then
   Set getEntityCode = entitySheet.Range(entitySheet.Cells(1, 3), entitySheet.Cells(1, finalCol))
Else
   Set getEntityCode = c
End If
End Function
```

But no matter how do it, when the statement execute to 
   Set c = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(i, finalCol))
It alway end up in the errHandler, and it always shows:Application-defined or object-defined error

I thought I have explicitely defined everything, can't see where I have done wrong, can anyone help me with this please, thank you very much.

Comment: Also to note that even with an error-less execution it will still run through the `ErrHandler` segment.  You may want to place a error-less execution method stop prior to the `ErrHandler` segment.  And if needed, have the `ErrHandler` segment redirect to the closing segment.  Alot of times you will see people annotate the error segment as `Err_Method` and the exit segment as `Exit_Method`, with `Method` being the name of the method.  Helps with readability and flow control.

Answer (score 2):

You never set a value for `finalCol`, therefore it is defaulting to 0.

Calling `Cells(1,0)` throws an error because Cells is 1 based instead of 0 based. Or rather, Row or Column 0 doesn't exist.

I recommend either having a line that goes: `finalCol = 1` or just use 1.